# What is this design pattern? How to use it?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I have class like this (simplified):

```
class Foo_p;
class Foo
{
private:
  Foo_p *p;
public:
  Foo();
  /* methods, etc... */
};
```

This class is a part of an API.
The Foo_p is all the private parts of the class, which are not 
declared in the class Foo itself as usual, but rather in a separate forward-declared class that is only used by the underlying implementation not visible on the outside.

I've seen this pattern used in a couple of projects, is there a name for it?

Also, how do I use it properly (e.g. exception safety, etc.)? Where should the actual implementation go? In class Foo, as usual, only using Foo_p for storage of data, or in the Foo_p class with Foo being just a wrapper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the pimpl idiom

See

- [Handle/Body Idiom](http://users.rcn.com/jcoplien/Patterns/C++Idioms/EuroPLoP98.html#HandleBody) - close cousin and the seminal idea for pimpl 
  ***EDIT** Found [an online copy of this original James Coplien talk](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/c++/EuroPLoP98.html#HandleBody)*
- [GotW #100: Compilation Firewalls (Difficulty: 6/10)](http://herbsutter.com/2011/11/04/gotw-100-compilation-firewalls/)
- [GotW #101: Compilation Firewalls, Part 2 (Difficulty: 8/10)](http://herbsutter.com/2011/11/16/gotw-101/) for the most recent on this

Comment: @pmb Thanks for the hint. Fixed all three links. _o.O permalinks... when they worked, they were so nice_ :(

Answer (score 8):

This is known is PIMPL. private/pointer-to-private implementation. The class, `Foo_p`, your class *would* have been is implemented privately and accessed through a pointer to it so that rather than displaying the true class to clients, they only get to see the public interface you chose to expose. It essentially abstracts away from the header the vestiges of implementation detail present in the `protected` and `private` members.

I've found it unwieldy in VC++- it breaks code completion. It is useful if you are very sure of your implementation and don't want the `private` and `protected` members on display in the header.

I put the actual implementation of class `Foo_p` in the cpp file for class `Foo`, although this may have been the cause of the code-completion breaking, at least I don't have to run the risk of the class being reused by inclusion of its header.

Comment: Don't both the headers and normal protection levels (public/private) "essentially hide the implementation"?

Comment: @Matthew: Unfortunately, no. You must include implementation headers, which can often be uncomfortable when they depend on for example the Windows headers, which are despicably bad.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: Yes, but only in the sense that you cannot access it, but you can still *see* it, when looking at the code.

Comment: Right, the Wikipedia quote Pubby gave helped me get it, particularly the point about binary compatibility.

Comment: Afaik, `protected` members are not moved from `Foo` to `Foo_p`, because they are parts of API too. Only `private` members are not part of API, so they are hidden from user's eyes.

Answer (score 2):

It's a d-pointer which is a type of opaque-pointer. Similar to the PIMPL idiom.

> One type of opaque pointer commonly used in C++ class declarations is
>   the d-pointer. The d-pointer is the only private data member of the
>   class and points to an instance of a struct. Named by Arnt Gulbrandsen
>   of Trolltech, this method allows class declarations to omit private
>   data members, except for the d-pointer itself.[6] The result is that
>   more of the class' implementation is hidden from view, that adding new
>   data members to the private struct does not affect binary
>   compatibility, and that the header file containing the class
>   declaration only has to #include those other files that are needed for
>   the class interface, rather than for its implementation. As a side
>   benefit, compiles are faster because the header file changes less
>   often. The d-pointer is heavily used in the Qt and KDE libraries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B